# Using LooseVersion to sort a list of objects that have a version string

Tags: python, django

I have a `Version` class that contains a `version_number` string, and can obtain a sorted list of those strings like so:

```
sorted_versions = [v.version_number for v in self.version_set]
sorted_versions.sort(key=LooseVersion)
```

This works great!

`sorted_versions: [u'1.6.3', u'1.7.0']`

However, I would like to maintain a sorted list of the actual `Version` objects, **not just their `version_number` properties**, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

In my head, I would like to see something like this:

```
sorted_versions = self.version_set
sorted_versions.sort(key=LooseVersion, property=version_number)
```

Resulting in:

`sorted_versions: [<Version: 1.6.3>, <Version: 1.7.0>]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
sorted(self.version_set, key=lambda v:LooseVersion(v.version_number))
```

Using `sorted()` here to avoid changing the original list which is what your 'would like to see' code would do if it worked.

Comment: Excellent - I had stumbled around with the lambda function (thinking it was the way to go) but couldn't quite get the syntax right. Very powerful stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it would be straight forward in implementing it by just modifying the key to the sorted function, to sort by any key as desired.
As an example consider a class

```
>>> class Version:
    def __init__(self,version_number):
        self.version_number = version_number
        self.blabla = random.randint(1,100)
```

and list of objects of Version

```
versions = [Version(i) for i in xrange(1,10)]
```

and you can sort it as below

```
sorted_versions = sorted(versions,key=lambda x:x.version_number)
```

and then if you see the values, it is sorted as per the property you desired